# How to move textbox events to other file - VB6 to VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, visual-studio-2005, upgrade

I am reworking old application built in VB6, with VB.NET and Visual Studio 2005.

It has one large form with like 50-60 text boxes, each with 2-3 event handlers, click, validating, keydown, enter etc...

The person who built this application didn't pay attention to keep good structure, so now the code file for the form is almost 2900 lines of code.

It has 3-4 important functions, other functions are just event handlers.

The problem is, each of those event handlers are defined as private and refer to objects/textboxes which exist only in the form code file.

What would be the right approach to move those event handlers to separate files?

Here is a sample code which I failed to move to separate file since I am noob VB.NET programmer:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Pol

    Private cboPol As MaskedTextBox = New MaskedTextBox()

    Private Sub cboPol_Enter(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) 'Handles cboPol.Enter
        ' TODO ova beshe zakomentirano. Da se proveri
        'meGodrag.SelStart = 0
        ' meGodrag.SelLength = 4
        'grstar = meGodrag.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboPol_KeyDown(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) 'Handles cboPol.KeyDown
        Dim KeyCode As Short = eventArgs.KeyCode
        Dim Shift As Short = eventArgs.KeyData \ &H10000
        If KeyCode = Constants.LEFT_ARROW_KEY Then
            'meNasmes.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboPol_KeyPress(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) 'Handles cboPol.KeyPress
        Dim KeyAscii As Short = Asc(eventArgs.KeyChar)
        'If KeyAscii = Constants.ENTER_KEY Then
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(Constants.TAB_KEY)
        'End If
        eventArgs.KeyChar = Chr(KeyAscii)
        If KeyAscii = 0 Then
            eventArgs.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what on earth does this have to do with c#??

Comment: @BugFinder removed it :D

Comment: If you just want to move the code to different *files* then you can define partial classes across multiple files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/partial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach to divide your mega-class in small parts is through the use of the concept of [Partial class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/partial)

Just create a new class file and name it as your big form class but add the keyword **Partial** before both classes. Now you can move all your event handlers to the second file freeing your main form from this stuff

See MSDN on [How to split a class into partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514141.aspx)

On a more structural solution you can check if it is possibile to create an unique event handler for the same event and force your controls to use the same event handler.

For example, if the action on the KeyDown event is the same for all controls then you can write a single event handler and tell your controls to use it

```
Private Sub allControls_KeyDown(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) 
     Handles cboPol.KeyDown, cboXXXX.KeyDown, cboYYYY.KeyDown etc.....
```

Or, if you find this approach too 'verbose', just use the Winforms designer to select the same event handler for all controls

Answer (score 1):

If the sample code you posted is indicative, it is possible a lot of the code is just for navigating the form.

You might be able to remove most of it by setting your tab order correctly.

For special navigation keys (e.g. left arrow key does something special, or you want the ENTER key to move to the next control like the TAB key), try setting `Form.KeyPreview = True` and having form-wide `KeyUp`/`KeyDown`/`KeyPress` routines.